# Banach Alaoglu Theorem - Proof for special case

Tags: lebesgue-integral, compactness, banach-spaces

I am interested in proving the following:

Given a measure space $(\Omega, \mu, \mathcal{F})$, then the following set is compact: $$\{ X \in L^2: \int |X|^2 d \mu \leq K \}$$

but I have no idea where to start given my lack of familiarity with dual spaces and my tremendously weak understanding of weak topologies.

Any references to an "elementary" proof of the Dunford-Pettis theorem would be massively appreciated, since I am trying to understand the claim [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391784/proof-of-dunford-pettis-theorem-in-kallenberg), in particular the part where it states "by compactness in $L^2$", which is the only part I do not understand.

Comment: You need to clarify the topology before mentioning something is "compact". For example, in general, that set is not compact with respect to the norm topology.

Comment: Ok fair enough.  I suppose I can rephrase my question as follows: Why is it that for any sequence of random variables in the set I specify in the question, there exists a subsequence which converges weakly in $L^2$?  In particular, is there any reference you know of which has an elementary proof of this?

Comment: Another comment: Sequential compactness and compactness, in general, are different. Which one do you want to prove? You should specify it in you question.

Comment: In this case they are the same since sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness on a metric space and weak convergence is metrizable.  But I wish to prove sequential compactness (via compactness or otherwise) in this case.

Comment: In general, the weak topology is not metrizable. 
To make the discussion precise. Let $X=L^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$
be the usual Hilbert space (with real scalar field $\mathbb{R})$.
By Riesz Representation, the dual space of $X$ is itself, i.e., $X^{\ast}=X$.
The topology we are talking about is $\mathcal{T}=\sigma(X^{\ast},X)$.

Comment: Let $B^{\ast}$ be the unit ball of $X^{\ast}$. Let $\mathcal{T}_{1}$
be the relative $\mathcal{T}$-topology on $B^{\ast}$. There is a
result that if $X$ is separable (i.e., containing a countable dense
subset. In Hilbert space setting, it is equivalent to having a countable
orthonormal base), then $\mathcal{T}_{1}$ is metrizable. However,
in general Hilbert space $L^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is not separable,
even if $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914570/regarding-metrizability-of-weak-weak-topology-and-separability-of-banach-spaces  and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42310/when-is-l2x-separable#:~:text=L2%20on%20any%20Lebesgue,space%20is%20not%20separable%20either.

Comment: Also this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380759/when-is-l2-mu-separable